# Why createdb console in postgresql is dissapearing?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to use postgresql database, but I cannot use createdb tool, after first launch window with terminal showed 4 some short time, and nothing happened. Now it is showing for less than second and vanishes. Tried already running on admin mode, reinstalling. 
Downloaded form https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/

I was using both installation versions (with and w/o graphical installer)

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, maybe it succeeded the first time?

Comment: I'm assuming you're just double-clicking it on Explorer or something? Run it in a command prompt.

Comment: I was running it from windows cmd, same result

Comment: Okay, solved, just ran commands in other window cmd tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, solved, just ran commands in other window cmd tool. I think this window is supposed to close. I have misunderstood som tutorial.